# AForge net simple shape detection error

Tags: c#, shapes, detection, aforge

I try to write simple shape detection app. I'm using sample from Aforge.net library. But I always get same error:

**cannot convert from 'AForge.Point[]' to 'System.Drawing.PointF[]'**

I try to change some things in ImageProcess method as well as in ToPointsArray, but effect is always the same. What else can I try? What I do wrong?

Here is code:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessImage((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName));
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Załadowanie obrazu niepowiodło się.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        //-------------------------------------

        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        //-------------------------------------

        ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();

        colorFilter.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.FillOutsideRange = false;

        colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

        //-------------------------------------

        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

        blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
        blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
        blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

        blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        //-------------------------------------

        SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);       // quadrilateral
        Pen brownPen = new Pen(Color.Brown, 2);   // quadrilateral with known sub-type
        Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);   // known triangle
        Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);     // triangle

        for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
        {
            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

            {
                List<IntPoint> corners;

                // is triangle or quadrilateral
                if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))
                {
                    // get sub-type
                    PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);

                    Pen pen;

                    if (subType == PolygonSubType.Unknown)
                    {
                        pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? brownPen : greenPen;
                    }

                    g.DrawPolygon(pen, ToPointsArray(corners));
                }
            }
        }

        redPen.Dispose();
        greenPen.Dispose();
        bluePen.Dispose();
        brownPen.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();

        // put new image to clipboard
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(bitmap);
        // and to picture box
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        UpdatePictureBoxPosition();
    }

    private Point[] ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
    {
        Point[] array = new Point[points.Count];

        for (int i = 0, n = points.Count; i < n; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new Point(points[i].X, points[i].Y);
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that AForge have there own `Point` struct so your `ToPointArray` method actually returns an Aforge Points array rather than an array of the needed .net Point. The simplest solution is to fully qualify the type you want to use, so your method would become

```
private System.Drawing.Point[] ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
{
    System.Drawing.Point[] array = new System.Drawing.Point[points.Count];
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to save a few characters you could alias the namespace with a `using` statement at the top of the class.

```
using NetPoint = System.Drawing.Point;

private NetPoint  ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
{
    NetPoint array = new NetPoint[points.Count];
    ...
}
```

As a side note this method could be shortened if linq is available to use. For example,

```
private System.Drawing.Point[] ToPointsArray(List<IntPoint> points)
{
    return points.Select(p => new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y)).ToArray();
}
```